# Appending <span> tag separately to every Array value using Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my first JavaScript project and I am having some difficulties to append the `<span>` tag separately to each value of an array. Whatever I tried so far results in a single `<span>` tag. What could be an elegant solution using native JavaScript? Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
let numbers = [1990, 1991, 1992];

let history = [];
let historyContainer = document.getElementById("output");
let para = document.createElement("p");
history.push(numbers.join(" "));
        
for (let k in history) {
 let text = document.createElement("span");
 let node = document.createTextNode(history[k]);
 text.appendChild(node)
 para.appendChild(text);
 historyContainer.appendChild(para);
}
```

```html
 
<div id="output">
 </div>
```

[Link to external jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/squashkid/mqg5oaz9/)

Comment: history.push(numbers.join(" ")); this line is why you are getting a single span tag, .join will join all number into 1 value so history is basically an array containing just 1 element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`history.push(numbers.join(" "));` is your problem - by the time the loop runs `history` is an array with a single value of `1990 1991 1992` because of the join. In fact you don't even need `history`, just iterate over `numbers`

```js
let numbers = [1990, 1991, 1992];
let historyContainer = document.getElementById("output");
let para = document.createElement("p");

for (let k in numbers) {
  let text = document.createElement("span");
  let node = document.createTextNode(numbers[k]);
  text.appendChild(node)
  para.appendChild(text);
  historyContainer.appendChild(para);
}
```

```css
span+span {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I would even go 1 step further to suggest some syntactic adjustments; using `const` instead of `let` for `historyContainer`, `para`. This isn't a huge deal, but since you are not intending to modify those variables, it's better suited that they be constant. If you wanted to be extra-safe, you should also check that `historyContainer` is actually populated with the expected DOM element.

Comment: @EvanBechtol agreed! Since it wasn't related to solving the problem I left it alone, but great call out.

Comment: @chazsolo Thanks a lot, this works very well. Funny that the solution is actually quite easy ... I probably got lost in too much code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some simple and fast solution, try this:

```js
var numbers = [1990, 1991, 1992],
  output = document.getElementById("output");

output.innerHTML = '<span>' + numbers.join('</span> <span>') + '</span>';
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let numbers = [1990, 1991, 1992];

numbers.forEach(function(item) {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  span.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("output").appendChild(span);
});
```

CSS:

```
span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following code :**

```
let numbers = [1990, 1991, 1992];
let history = [];
let historyContainer = document.getElementById("output");
let para = document.createElement("p");
history.push(numbers.join(" "));
numbers.forEach(function(element){
  console.log(element);
    let text = document.createElement("span");
    let node = document.createTextNode(element);
  text.appendChild(node)
    para.appendChild(text);
  historyContainer.appendChild(para);
});
```

**Expected HTML :**

[image]